# CoreData Import from XML Paradox

Tags: mysql, objective-c, core-data

I have a mysql database that has several tables, some tables relate to others by an ID field. Now I am trying to import this data into my app and I would like to be able to use the relation properties of CoreData. The problem comes when I am importing my data (via XML) while all of the relationships are defined in the XML, some come later than others.

What is the best way to deal with linking the relationships after import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you need to parse your XML twice, once to get the entities created and again to create the relationships between them.